# How can I configure BlueJeans so that the webcam/microphone/screenshare bar doesn't hide automatically?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) 2.5.2270 for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

By default, during a call, the webcam/microphone/screenshare bar hides automatically:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent BlueJeans from hiding this bar?

I want to be able to check at any time whether the the webcam/microphone/screenshare is activated, and I don't want to have to mousover onto the BlueJeans window to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlueJeans has recently (end of 2018 / early 2019) introduced the option "always show video and layout controls":

[image]

---

Former solution to go around it, which isn't necessary anymore for recent versions of BlueJeans:

One way around: when the `people` sidebar is selected, then  the webcam/microphone/screenshare bar doesn't hide automatically:

[image]